# Заполнение только диагонали в двумерном массиве (Java)

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно получить массив с заполненной диагональю (слева на право) в консоле.
Такого вида:

```
1  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0
0  0  0  1  0
0  0  0  0  1
```

Сделать нужно через цикл

```
public class TwoDArrayLeftToRight {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int N = 5;
        int twoD[][] = new int[N][N];
        int i, j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                twoD[i][j] = 1;
            }
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
                System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + "  ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

из такого кода я получаю только массив из единиц, как его пообрезать?

```
1  1  1  1  1  
1  1  1  1  1  
1  1  1  1  1  
1  1  1  1  1  
1  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Не знаю, обнуляется ли в java распределенная память. Если да - внутренний цикл не нужен. - Да, не нужен.)*

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  /*for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    twoD[i][j] = 0;
  }*/
  twoD[i][i] = 1;
}
```

Comment: @zRrr спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TwoDArrayLeftToRight {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int N = 5;
        int twoD[][] = new int[N][N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
             twoD[i][i] = 1;
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                System.out.printf("%3d",twoD[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            twoD[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            twoD[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]